# Given two positive numbers $x,y.$ Prove that $\left|x\ln x-y\ln y\right|\leq\sqrt[3]{\left|x^{2}-y^{2}\right|}+\sqrt[3]{\left|x^{2}-y^{2}\right|^{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, intuition, integral-inequality

> **Problem 1**. Given two poistive numbers $x, y.$ Prove that
> $$\left | x\ln x- y\ln y \right |\leq\sqrt[3]{\left | x^{2}- y^{2} \right |}+ \sqrt[3]{\left | x^{2}- y^{2} \right |^{2}}$$

There exists a solution using the integral to solve, without loss of generality, assume that $x\geq y\Rightarrow t= x^{2}- y^{2}\geq 0,$ let $b= y^{2},$ we need to prove the following integral inequality in 2 cases : $b\geq\frac{1}{e^{2}}$ either $b+ t\leq\frac{1}{e^{2}}$
$$\left | \int_{b}^{b+ t}\frac{\ln x+ 2}{4\sqrt{x}}{\rm d}x \right |\leq\sqrt[3]{t}+ \sqrt[3]{t^{2}}$$
**Case 1**. $b\geq\frac{1}{e^{2}}$
$$\int_{b}^{b+ t}\frac{\ln x+ 2}{4\sqrt{x}}{\rm d}x\leq\sqrt[3]{t}+ \sqrt[3]{t^{2}}\Leftrightarrow\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\ln\left ( x+ b \right )+ 2}{4\sqrt{x+ b}}{\rm d}x\leq\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}}+ \frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}{\rm d}x$$
Substitute $g\left ( b \right )= \frac{\ln\left ( x+ b \right )+ 2}{4\sqrt{x+ b}}\Rightarrow {g}'\left ( b \right )= -\frac{\ln\left ( x+ b \right )}{8\left ( x+ b \right )^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

If $t\geq 1- \frac{1}{e^{2}}$
$$H= \int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}}+ \frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}- \frac{\ln\left ( x+ b \right )+ 2}{4\sqrt{x+ b}}{\rm d}x= \int_{0}^{1- \frac{1}{e^{2}}}\frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}}+ \frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}- \frac{\ln\left ( x+ b \right )+ 2}{4\sqrt{x+ b}}{\rm d}x+$$
$$+ \int_{1- \frac{1}{e^{2}}}^{t}\frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}}+ \frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}- \frac{\ln\left ( x+ b \right )+ 2}{4\sqrt{x+ b}}{\rm d}x\geq\int_{0}^{1- \frac{1}{e^{2}}}\frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}}+ \frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}- \frac{\ln\left ( x+ b \right )+ 2}{4\sqrt{x+ b}}{\rm d}x+$$
$$\int_{1- \frac{1}{e^{2}}}^{t}\frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}}+ \frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}- \frac{\ln\left ( x+ \frac{1}{e^{2}} \right )+ 2}{4\sqrt{x+ \frac{1}{e^{2}}}}{\rm d}x= \int_{1- \frac{1}{e^{2}}}^{t}\frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}}+ \frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}- \frac{\ln\left ( x+ \frac{1}{e^{2}} \right )+ 2}{4\sqrt{x+ \frac{1}{e^{2}}}}{\rm d}x$$
$$+ \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{b}\ln b+ \left ( 1- e^{-2} \right )^{-\frac{1}{3}}+ \left ( 1- e^{-2} \right )^{-\frac{2}{3}}- \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{b+ 1- e^{-2}}\ln\left ( b+ 1- e^{-2} \right )$$
Let $f\left ( x \right )= \frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}}+ \frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}- \frac{\ln\left ( x+ \frac{1}{e^{2}} \right )+ 2}{4\sqrt{x+ \frac{1}{e^{2}}}},$ since $f\left ( x \right )\leq 0\,{\rm as}\,36.29678351< x< 1161.52586,$
$$f\left ( x \right )\geq 0\,{\rm as}\,1- e^{-2}< x< 36.29678351, 1161.52586\leq x$$
$$\Rightarrow H= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{b}\ln b+ \left ( 1- e^{-2} \right )^{-\frac{1}{3}}+ \left ( 1- e^{-2} \right )^{-\frac{2}{3}}- \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{b+ 1- e^{-2}}\ln\left ( b+ 1- e^{-2} \right )+$$
$$+ \int_{1- \frac{1}{e^{2}}}^{1161.52586}\frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}}+ \frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}- \frac{\ln\left ( x+ \frac{1}{e^{2}} \right )+ 2}{4\sqrt{x+ \frac{1}{e^{2}}}}{\rm d}x\geq 1.431081083- 1.123709381> 0$$
If $t\leq 1- e^{-2}$
$$H= \int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}}+ \frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}- \frac{\ln\left ( x+ b \right )+ 2}{4\sqrt{x+ b}}{\rm d}x\geq\int_{0}^{t}x^{-\frac{2}{3}}+ \frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}- \frac{1}{2}{\rm d}x\geq 0$$
**Case 2**. $b+ t\leq\frac{1}{e^{2}}$
$$H= \int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}}+ \frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}+ \frac{\ln\left ( x+ b \right )+ 2}{4\sqrt{x+ b}}{\rm d}x\geq\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}}+ \frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}+ \frac{\ln x+ 2}{4\sqrt{x}}{\rm d}x\geq$$
$$\geq -\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{t}\ln t+ t^{\frac{1}{3}}+ t^{\frac{2}{3}}\geq 0$$

> Problem 2. Given two real numbers $x, y.$ Prove that
> $$\left | \sin x- \sin y \right |\leq\left | x- y \right |$$

I'm having trouble using the way that we used in problem 1, I don't know how to devide it into some cases. On the other hand does there exist a nicer solution for *problem 1* ; and another problem(s) as same as these ones as above, thank you.

Comment: The second inequality is well-known and follows immediately from the mean-value theorem. I do not see how that should be related to the first problem.

Comment: @RiverLi, these are very much related, you can substitute $x= y+ t,$ as same as above.

Comment: Problem 2: WLOG, suppose $y>x$, then $LHS =|\int_x^y \cos(t)dt| \le \int_x^y |\cos(t)|dt \le \int_x^y 1dt =y-x$. Here I use integral to solve the problem.

Comment: Common way for what kind of problems exactly? They look a bit different to me. The second is of the form $|f(x)-f(y)| \le |x-y|$ (so that the mean-value theorem can be used directly) and the first one is not (and seems to be more difficult). So what are “all these problems”?

Comment: @haidangel Many users will help you. I often can not solve your problem.

Comment: @haidangel A similar problem (I think $\sqrt{2}$ can be improved to $\sqrt{\frac{9}{5}}$): Let $x, y > 0$. Prove that
$$ \left| \frac{\sin x}{x} - \frac{\sin y}{y} \right|
\le \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\left| \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y} \right|}.$$

Comment: @RiverLi, nice results.

Comment: @haidangel Your solution using integral is nice! By the way, do not upvote me frequently :).

Comment: Roger that, sir

Comment: @haidangel Thanks. Actually, often my solution is not nice (e.g., BW).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Alternative solution*:

First we give some auxiliary results (Facts 1-2). The proofs are given at the end.

*Fact 1*: Let $t > 1$ and $u > 0$. Then
$$(t^2-1)^{1/3}u^{-1} + (t^2 - 1)^{2/3}u - t\ln t - 3(t-1)\ln u \ge 0.$$

*Fact 2*: Let $t > 1$ and $u > 0$. Then
$$(t^2-1)^{1/3}u^{-1} + (t^2 - 1)^{2/3}u + t\ln t + 3(t-1)\ln u \ge 0.$$

Now, WLOG, assume $x > y$.

Let $t = \frac{x}{y}$. Then $t > 1$. The desired inequality is written as
$$|t\ln t + (t-1)\ln y | \le (t^2-1)^{1/3}y^{-1/3} + (t^2 - 1)^{2/3}y^{1/3}. \tag{1}$$
It suffices to prove that
$$t\ln t + (t-1)\ln y  \le (t^2-1)^{1/3}y^{-1/3} + (t^2 - 1)^{2/3}y^{1/3}, \tag{2}$$
and
$$- t\ln t - (t-1)\ln y  \le (t^2-1)^{1/3}y^{-1/3} + (t^2 - 1)^{2/3}y^{1/3}. \tag{3}$$
By Facts 1-2, (2) and (3) are both true.

We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

*Proof of Fact 1*: Denote LHS by $f(u)$. We have
\begin{align}
f'(u) &= - (t^2-1)^{1/3}u^{-2} + (t^2 - 1)^{2/3} - 3(t-1)u^{-1}\\
&= \frac{1}{u^2}(u - u_0)\Big[(t^2-1)^{2/3}u + (t^2-1)^{1/3} u_0^{-1}\Big]
\end{align}
where $u_0 = \frac{3(t-1) + \sqrt{(t - 1)(13t - 5)}}{2(t^2 - 1)^{2/3}}$.

Thus $f'(u_0) = 0$, $f'(u) < 0$ on $(0, u_0)$, and $f'(u) > 0$ on $(u_0, \infty)$.
Thus, $f(u) \ge f(u_0)$ for all $u > 0$.

It suffices to prove $f(u_0) \ge 0$ that is
\begin{align}
&\frac{2(t^2 - 1)}{3(t-1) + \sqrt{(t - 1)(13t - 5)}} + \frac{3(t-1) + \sqrt{(t - 1)(13t - 5)}}{2}\\
 &\quad - t\ln t - 3(t-1)\ln \frac{3(t-1) + \sqrt{(t - 1)(13t - 5)}}{2(t^2 - 1)^{2/3}} \ge 0.
\end{align}
The proof is not difficult (Hint: Let $\frac{13t-5}{t-1} = w^2$.). We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

*Proof of Fact 2*: Denote LHS by $g(u)$. We have
\begin{align}
g'(u) &= - (t^2-1)^{1/3}u^{-2} + (t^2 - 1)^{2/3} + 3(t-1)u^{-1}\\
&= \frac{1}{u^2}(u - u_1)\Big[(t^2 - 1)^{2/3} u + \frac{3(t-1) + \sqrt{(t - 1)(13t - 5)}}{2}\Big]
\end{align}
where $u_1 = \frac{2(t^2 - 1)^{1/3}}{3(t-1) + \sqrt{(t - 1)(13t - 5)}}$.

Thus $g'(u_1) = 0$, $g'(u) < 0$ on $(0, u_1)$, and $g'(u) > 0$ on $(u_1, \infty)$.
Thus, $g(u) \ge g(u_1)$ for all $u > 0$.

It suffices to prove $g(u_1) \ge 0$ that is
\begin{align}
& \frac{3(t-1) + \sqrt{(t-1)(13t-5)}}{2} + \frac{2(t^2 - 1)}{3(t-1) + \sqrt{(t-1)(13t-5)}}\\
&\quad + t\ln t + 3(t-1)\ln \frac{2(t^2 - 1)^{1/3}}{3(t-1) + \sqrt{(t - 1)(13t - 5)}} \ge 0.
\end{align}
The proof is not difficult (Hint: Let $\frac{13t-5}{t-1} = w^2$.). We are done.

Comment: I'm sorry, there are no notifications for me, +1as always.

Comment: @haidangel Can your nice method using integral work for any other examples (e.g., in MSE)?

Comment: Yeah, I'll try.

Comment: Another nice method_ https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4035339/822157, hope you enjoy it !

Comment: @haidangel Another problem (Not for this question)? How about: Since $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{{\rm d}x}{x^{2}e^{x^{2}}} \geq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{{\rm d}x}{x^{2}e^{x^{2}}}\geq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{{\rm d}x}{x^2 \mathrm{e}}$ and $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{{\rm d}x}{x^2 \mathrm{e}} = \infty$, we have $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{{\rm d}x}{x^{2}e^{x^{2}}} = \infty$.

Comment: That's right, thank you.