# I have confirmed that the left integral diverges by the special value of the Lambert function in the equation $xe^{x^{2}}=1,$ anymore of it ??

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, continuity, alternative-proof, lambert-w

> **Problem**. Prove that
> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{{\rm d}x}{x^{2}e^{x^{2}}}= \infty$$

Indeed, that's true because
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{x^{2}}{\rm d}x= 1/2\int_{0}^{\infty}{\left ( x^{2} \right )}'e^{x^{2}}{\rm d}x= \infty$$
and there exists a numbers $x_{0}\geq 0$ so that $x_{0}e^{x_{0}^{2}}= 1,$ therefore
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{{\rm d}x}{x^{2}e^{x^{2}}}\geq\int_{0}^{x_{0}}\frac{{\rm d}x}{x^{2}e^{x^{2}}}\geq\int_{0}^{x_{0}}\frac{{\rm d}x}{x}= \infty$$
I want to see any simplier solutions about my problem, that's my pleasure.

*Edit*, there are many complainings when I used $> \infty$ at the recent, and many of mathmaticians you can see here_ https://youtu.be/z1k8BUYmHz4, I want my equation clearer I don't do it on purpose

Comment: What does $X>\infty$ mean?

Comment: It is diversed.

Comment: $X<\infty$ has a well-defined meaning as is $X=\infty$ or $X=\pm\infty$, but $X>\infty$ has none.

Comment: For example $e^{n}< \infty\,{\rm as}\,n\rightarrow\infty,$ but $\lim e^{n}> \infty$ will be easier to understand.

Comment: If nonsense is easier to understand, then yes, but that is meaningless.

Comment: OK, I'll edit smth for you.

Comment: I literally edited it to $\to\infty$, which is the most widely used notation.

Comment: @user10354138, there are no $> \infty$ more, hope you enjoy my problem instead of the other side of it.

Comment: @vitamind, I think that $\to\infty$ is to the divergence, but in my view, I like to use $\geq\infty$ to show the usefulness of my method.

Comment: @haidangel Look at the graph of your integrand. The problem is at $0$. To make it even clearer you can look and integrate over $\mathbb{R}$ by multiplying your integral by $2$. Now you have the problem from both sides.

Comment: @vitamind, cool

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty\geqslant\int_0^1\geqslant\frac1e\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^2}$?

Comment: Mr. @RiverLi has just told us the same, thank you at all..